# How Mining Works on Private Ethereum Blockchain Networks?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, mining, go-ethereum

I'm a little bit confused about how the process of mining works on private ethereum blockchains.

I know that in public networks the mining processes is distributed among aleatory miners.

But in private networks, should I choose the users who's gonna mine?

Comment: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because better to ask at https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: You control the miners on your own private network.

Generally speaking, private networks are implemented specifically to isolate your environment. This could be due to wanting to secure your data from the public network or simply because you want to have an environment for dev/QA. Therefore, you wouldn't want any unknown miners attached to your private network.

One use case that may cause you to want expose your network to other entities would be if you were creating a consortium that others could join. Something like sellers joining an Amazon private network in order to handle fulfillment. Even in this case, the miners on the network would be setup in a way similar to traditional private networks today where access is strictly controlled by the owner of the network (with firewalls, etc).

If you're interested in setting up your own private network, the [Geth documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Setting-up-private-network-or-local-cluster) has a pretty good write up.